# Preprocess the text contained in the cells of an excel column using Orange

Tags: excel, orange, data-preprocessing

I would like to preprocess (lower case, remove stopwords, lemmatization, remove punctuation ecc...) the text contained in the cells of a column of an excel file using the software ORANGE (by the preprocessing widget). the only way i can get and see the preprocessing done is by using the "word cloud" widget, but i can't save a new excel file to which preprocessing has been applied. how could I do? thank you all

**in summary I want to preprocess a text using Orange and save the resulting text as a new document**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are right; it doesn't work well with an Excel file.
But there is a workaround:

[image: Orange workflow to preprocess text form Excel file]

The output will be related to your way to preprocess text.

P.S.: I forgot to remove the count column from the word cloud in my WF.